# как удалить задачу в amocrm?

Tags: php, api

Как редактировать понял, но мне надо именно удалить, как это сделать? Не нашел что-то у них в документации.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Зачем тебе удалять задачи? Закрой и забудь. https://www.amocrm.ru/developers/content/crm_platform/tasks-api#tasks-complete